# INSERT IGNORE - How can I tell if inserted?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going to need an SQL query that would `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (or `INSERT IGNORE INTO`) my table.

I need to know if an update *actually* took place or rather a new row was inserted.

A good reference was this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596390/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-key-do-nothing-just-dont-complain-to-the-error), unfortunately there's no answer to the action taken.

As for now I am using INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl` (`CLIENT_ID`, `COMP_ID`, `DATETIME`) VALUES (12334,32,NOW())
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    `COMP_ID`=VALUES(`COMP_ID`), `DATETIME`=VALUES(`DATETIME`);";
```

and check the affected_rows value.
If affected_rows equals 1, means -> new row inserted
If affected_rows equals 2, means -> row updated

I'd like no change to happen in case of a duplicate, but I would like to know a duplicate exists.

Using MYSQL

Comment: Buried [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) - a new insert will return 1 affected row, while an update will return 2.  `INSERT IGNORE` will return 0 if ignored, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Inspect the number of rows affected:

- A return value of `1` means an `INSERT` occurred
- A return value of `2` means an `UPDATE` occurred

If you're using JDBC, this is the `int` return value of the `update()` or `execute()` call.

All frameworks have a way of passing this value back to you, for example Hibernate's `Query.executeUpdate()` returns this `int` value.

Comment: Affected rows: the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query. I don't think it will help.

Comment: @RomanNewaza Yes it does help. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html