# Update nothing on duplicate key exist

Tags: mysql, sql, c#-4.0

I'm using the query `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` in order to insert a record into the table, and if a row with duplicate keys already exists, this results in triggering an update.

I don't want any updates being performed on an existing row, if exist.

What should I do to update nothing when a row with duplicate keys exist?

Comment: Put more effort to your questions pls... Elaborate more and provide details of your problem.

Comment: You could see if there's an element with duplicate key before inserting

Comment: **Duplicate of:** [stackoverflow.com/q/4596390](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4596390/1454514)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set the unique value with the original value, (*Assuming `ProductID` is unique*) eg,

```
INSERT INTO CART (ProductID, Quantity)
VALUES (1, 100)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ProductID = ProductID;
```