# Update MySQL table and ignore duplicate entries

Tags: mysql

I created a table that contains a UNIQUE 'mobile_no' like

```
09727048248
9727048248
9824578564
9898998998
```

Then I am going to check whether or not the mobile number is valid, and if it's valid then I want to change it into the proper format like 919727048248.

For that I called update query like..

```
update bccontacts 
set mobile_no='919727048248' 
where mobile_no=09727048248
```

The first time it ran successfully, but the second time it replied

> ERROR 1062 (23000):Duplicate entry '919727048248' for key 'mobile_no'

Because there is already a unique key set for the 'mobile_no'.

So is there any other query which will `IGNORE DUPLICATE KEY ON UPDATE`?

Comment: Possible duplicate [4596390](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596390/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-key-do-nothing-just-dont-complain-to-the-error)

Answer (score 121):

Use `UPDATE IGNORE`:

```
update IGNORE bccontacts 
set mobile_no='919727048248' 
where mobile_no=09727048248
```

More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: I would also add a status column in order to be able to prune duplicates. UPDATE IGNORE targetTable SET status=9, targetCol=value ; DELETE FROM targetTable WHERE status !=9;

Comment: I would recommend against using UPDATE IGNORE as it is unsafe. As the documentation says: [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)
"UPDATE IGNORE statements, including those having an ORDER BY clause, are flagged as unsafe for statement-based replication. (**This is because the order in which the rows are updated determines which rows are ignored.***) Such statements produce a warning in the error log when using statement-based mode and are written to the binary log using the row-based format when using MIXED mode."

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared the mobile number as the primary key in your table, then you can’t have the same mobile number twice in your table. Have a look at the [MySQL UPDATE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Comment: Mobile number declared as UNIQUE_KEY, that i already mentioned in my question..by the way i got another solution see next answer..