# How to prevent duplicate record inserts with PDO

Tags: php, html, sql-server, pdo

I want to try to setup something where if user already submitted a dept key and current date it will stop the record from being inserted. It will give out an error saying duplicate record entered try again.

Here is part of my insert page but it is not working

```
$stmt= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_lighting(Department, 
    areaCode, offtime, gytime, ftime, ini, 
    sat_ob_department, sat_ib_department,
    sat_ob_onTime,sat_ib_onTime,
    sat_ob_offTime, sat_ib_offTime,
    ob_signature,ib_signature, 
    deptkey, comments,ib_comments,ob_comments,Requestdate

 ) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM tbl_lighting where deptkey = $deptkey AND Requestdate= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST["Department"]);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST["areaCode"]);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST["offtime"]);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST["gytime"]);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $_POST["ftime"]);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $_POST["ini"]);
$stmt->bindParam(7, $_POST["sat_ob_department"]);
$stmt->bindParam(8, $_POST["sat_ib_department"]);
$stmt->bindParam(9, $_POST["sat_ob_onTime"]);
$stmt->bindParam(10, $_POST["sat_ib_onTime"]);
$stmt->bindParam(11, $_POST["sat_ob_offTime"]);
$stmt->bindParam(12, $_POST["sat_ib_offTime"]);
$stmt->bindParam(13, $_POST["ob_signature"]);
$stmt->bindParam(14, $_POST["ib_signature"]);
$stmt->bindParam(15, $_POST["deptkey"]);
$stmt->bindParam(16, $_POST["comments"]);
$stmt->bindParam(17, $_POST["ib_comments"]);
$stmt->bindParam(18, $_POST["ob_comments"]);
$stmt->bindParam(19, $_POST["Requestdate"]);


$stmt->execute();
```

Here is my submit form

```
<form action = "insert_process.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="form" id="form" method ="post" class="style1">

<table align="center" id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
<br><br>
<tr>
<td colspan="7"><h1 align="center">Lighting Schedule Form</h1></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Department</th><th style="width: 75px">Area Code</th><th style="width: 144px">Off Time</th><th>Grave Yard On Time</th><th>First Shift OnTime</th><th width="125px">Comments Or Date By</th><th>Initials</th></tr>

<tr>

    <!--First row accross on the table-->
<td><select name="Department" id="Department" >
            <option value ="">Please select ...</option>
            <option value ="Upstairs Hang East">Upstairs Hang East</option>
            <option value ="Upstairs Hang West">Upstairs Hang West</option>
            <option value ="RDR">RDR</option>
            </select></td>
<td style="width: 75px"><input id="areaCode" name="areaCode" onkeydown="return false;" type="text"/></td>
<td style="width: 144px"><input class="offtime" id="offtime" name="offtime"  type="text" /></td>
<td><input id="gytime" name="gytime" type="text"></td>
<td><input id="ftime" name="ftime" type="text" ></td>
<td><input id="comments" name="comments" type="text"></td>
<td><input id="ini" name="ini" type="text" style="width: 68px" /></td>
</tr>


<input id="deptkey" name="deptkey" onkeydown="return false;" type="hidden"/>

    <!--end-->
```

Comment: *"How to prevent duplicate record inserts with PDO"* - Instead of checking through a whole bunch of code, set a unique constraint on the given column(s), no?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596390/insert-on-duplicate-key-do-nothing     Create a unique paired key.

Comment: Sidenote: You do have your closing `</form>` tag, correct? Plus, you've some JS happening too; harder to say if that's part of the problem or not.

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. This to check for possible errors you may be having, and not seeing them because you may not be checking for them.

Comment: I have unique key for each department I wanted to make sure user did not enter that key and today's date into the record because the next day the same key will be entered again

Comment: I  need it so when a user enters a record that has already been entered with a duplicate key (like for instance department RDR is key C) also by today's date too, to alert them that it has already been entered. The reason I need it for today’s date also is 
because the next day they will be entering that key again and I don’t want it to alert them unless they o it that day again. If I do figure a correct way of doing it I will post the answer so that anyone else in same situation can learn from this.

Comment: @fred sorry this is partial code I do have closing form I can update it with all the code if needed everything is working when i remove WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM tbl_lighting where deptkey = $deptkey AND Requestdate= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) I just through that in there to kind of give a clue on where I want this to go. I knew it might have not worked.

Comment: maybe I should delete the question until I have a better way of presenting it and put an example on js fiddle

Comment: The correct way of doing it is adding unique constraint, inserting and in case of duplicate record - catching the exception and notifying the user. **There is no other possible correct way**. What @Fred-ii- told you is how you do it. Unique constraint + PDO in exception mode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you have to escape you're php variable $deptkey like this, and uppercase the WHERE conditionl like this :

```
$stmt= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_lighting(Department, 
    areaCode, offtime, gytime, ftime, ini, 
    sat_ob_department, sat_ib_department,
    sat_ob_onTime,sat_ib_onTime,
    sat_ob_offTime, sat_ib_offTime,
    ob_signature,ib_signature, 
    deptkey, comments,ib_comments,ob_comments,Requestdate
```

) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM tbl_lighting WHERE deptkey = '".$deptkey."' AND Requestdate= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)");

Answer (score 3):

The essence of the problem is stopping a duplicate record and I'll explain why unique keys and exceptions using PDO are the correct way.

Databases maintain relations and store data. One of the jobs of the database is handling concurrency and storing data. Preventing duplicate records in the database is handled by creating unique keys, hence disallowing such records appearing at all in the data model. Databases handle multiple users connecting at the same time, who in turn insert some data.

What I see people doing is selecting a record, then checking whether it exists and if 0 rows are returned - they proceed with the insert. This is bad approach and not only does it hurt performance, it can often fail in preventing duplicate records. Reason for this is because there's a slight delay between PHP (or any language) and MySQL server (or any other database server). By the time you've selected the data and done the check, a small amount of time has passed - let's say 1 millisecond. During that time, another user might have connected and gone through the same process (select, check if 0 rows, if 0 insert). Since the two users are doing the same thing at the same time, both would get the information back about the result - because of the tiny delay between PHP process and MySQL. In turn, you can end up with duplicate records. You also spent time selecting something and sending it through socket connection.

It's much quicker to just let the database handle all the work. Since insert cannot occur due to unique constraint, it's much easier for you to just insert and let the insert fail (it's much less "expensive" than selecting and checking in PHP). Database(s) also take care of concurrency or "multiple users at the same time". This means your database knows the state of its data, and it's best if you let it continue doing so. You also end up with less code.

Your algorithm should be this:

- Obtain input
- Prepare the statement
- Perform the insert
- If exception rises, there was a duplicate record (you can check the code returned by your db to be sure it's because of duplicate key or something else)

What Fred said in his comment is the correct, and the only correct way of really preventing the duplicate insert. Also, since you are using prepared statements, you need not specify any variables in your statement. Just bind everything and let the PDO take care of sanitizing user input.

Comment: Is there an example you can show me with a link. i am not an advance php programmer.