# PHP/SQL insert a record if it not exists in that row on the db, form an scandir array

Tags: php, sql, scandir

I tried it with if exists on sql but it says error.

```
if (isset($_POST['ReScan'])){
$dateien = 'dateien/';
$directoryscanarray = scandir($dateien);
print_r($directoryscanarray);

$arrlength = count($directoryscanarray);

for($x = 2; $x <  $arrlength; $x++) {
$foldername = $directoryscanarray[$x];
$sql = "INSERT INTO localfiles (foldername) VALUES ('$foldername')";
```

maybe:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS SELECT foldername FROM localfiles WHERE name='$foldername'";
```

Comment: Just make foldername unique in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the foldername an unique key and use

```
INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

Where on duplicate key you would just say the key equals itself

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY (do nothing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596390/insert-on-duplicate-key-do-nothing)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (not tested):

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO localfiles (foldername) VALUES ('$foldername') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field_1="value_1", field_2="value_2" WHERE foldername='$foldername'";
```