# Unique key error as duplicate key in mysql perl script

Tags: mysql, perl

I have one sql table, which has Primary key which is combination of two columns of same table as shown below:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`CONN_ID`,`PWORD`)
```

I am migrating the data from one database to another database using perl script.

```
$select = $dbh1->prepare("SELECT * FROM db2");
$insert = $dbh2->prepare("INSERT INTO db1 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$dbh2->do( 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;' );
$select->execute;
while (  my($PWORD,$CASE,$SPECIAL_XP,$ENA_TRANS,$TRANS,$DESC,$COMP,$SER,$CONN_ID,$S_ID,$EXT) = $select->fetchrow_array )
{
  $insert->execute($PWORD,$CASE,$SPECIAL_XP,$ENA_TRANS,$TRANS,$DESC,$COMP,$SER,$CONN_ID,$S_ID,$EXT,'NULL');
}
$dbh2->do( 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;' );
```

While running the script i am getting the following error, how to overcome that error and copy the data without any discrepancies.

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '10560-???' for key 'PRIMARY' at ./upgrade.sh.
```

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `MDB_KEYWORD` (
`PWORD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`CASE` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`SPECIAL_XP` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`ENA_TRANS` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`TRANS` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
 `DESC` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`COMP` blob,
`SER` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`CONN_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`S_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`EXT` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`U_LIST` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`CONN_ID`,`KEYWORD`),
KEY `FK_KEYWORD_SERVICECONN` (`SER`),
KEY `FK_KEYWORD_SERVICE` (`S_ID`),
KEY `FK_KEYWORD_EXTID` (`EXT`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_KEYWORD_DRIVERCONN` FOREIGN KEY (`CONN_ID`) REFERENCES     `PDB_PROFILE` (`PR_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_KEYWORD_EXTID` FOREIGN KEY (`EXT_ID`) REFERENCES `PDB_PROFILE` (`PR_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_KEYWORD_SERVICE` FOREIGN KEY (`S_ID`) REFERENCES `PDB_PROFILE` (`PR_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_KEYWORD_SERVICECONN` FOREIGN KEY (`SER`) REFERENCES `PDB_PROFILE` (`PR_ID`)
```

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

The only difference between the tow tables is :

ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;  DB1

ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;  DB2

Comment: Where is your script?

Comment: Please check update question with script and schema

Comment: Does both table have the same structure?

Comment: Yes same structure, except 'U_LIST' is extra column in db2.

Comment: Try [on duplicate key ignore](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4596409/5260590)

Comment: @Pionas If i ignore the duplicate key, then it will not insert. i want all data to be migrated from db1 to db2 ignoring that duplicate key error.

Comment: You try `INSERT IGNORE`? Maybe remove the primary key and add it to the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two rows with the same primary key.
It appears that you have two rows with CONN_ID = 10560 and PWORD = ??? in your data set.

Remove the primary key or clean up your data (get rid of the rows with identical primary keys).

Another possible cause of the problem is the `SELECT *` and the `INSERT INTO db1 VALUES ...`. You should *always* name the columns you want to retrieve and insert to avoid problems with column order etc.

I saw that the table schema has

```
PRIMARY KEY (`CONN_ID`,`KEYWORD`)
```

which is different from

```
PRIMARY KEY (`CONN_ID`,`PWORD`)
```

PS: This question isn't really perl-related as-is.

Comment: sorry, its typo mistake PRIMARY KEY (`CONN_ID`,`PWORD`) is right for both db

Comment: no, if do insert ignore, it just doesnt throw error, no data is inserted

Comment: Just print every row before you insert it then you will see which row(s) is causing the problems.

Comment: See the PWORD and CONN_ID in db1 :                                                              `PWORD ` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL.....                                                                  in db2 its schema is:                                                                                                      `PWORD ` varchar(255) NOT NULL,                                                                   does this cause issue?

Comment: insert a line in the while loop before `$insert->execute`: `print "'$PWORD'\t'$CONN_ID'\n";`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103072/discussion-between-neuhaus-and-ashu).