# Mysql if data exists then do not insert it again

Tags: php, mysql

I use this code below for getting data from a different website by using PHP curl function.everything is working fine but I am getting duplicate data into my database when the website will reload or refresh.
[duplicate data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvNyC.png)

does there have any why based on this code below to stop inserting duplicate data on reload if the data already exist in the Mysql database? I search on google about this issue but don't get any useful information.

```
if(isset($_POST['url'],$_POST['theme'])){

    $db = new Mysqli("localhost" , "iamniloy_wp###" , "(5uSE6[3OP" , "iamniloy_#@");

    $url = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['url']);
    $theme = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['theme']);


    $query = "INSERT INTO twist_data ( url,theme ) VALUES ('$url','$theme')";
    $db->query($query);

    }
```

Comment: You can use a Try Catch, and just ignore the duplicate ID exception, provided you have a unique field.

Comment: What about the data makes it duplicate?  The url, the theme, or both?

Comment: create a UNIQUE index and isn't too late to ALTER your db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't add a unique index for whatever reason, you can use `EXISTS` to check for an already existing record:

```
INSERT INTO twist_data (url, theme)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$url','$theme') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM twist_data WHERE url = '$url' AND theme = '$theme'
)
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1` ? :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Who put that there!?

Comment: I heard of some goblins on SO ;-)

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen .

Answer (score 0):

You should change the structure of your table to have a unique index on the relevant columns.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `twist_data` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `url` (`url`)
```

This way you will not able to insert the same `url` to your table.

If you need the `unique` to be on both the `url` and the `theme` you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE `twist_data` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `url_theme` (`url`, `theme`)
```

More information in the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: You might also mention the `INSERT IGNORE` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Select count query where in you will check if the data exists or not then
make an if condition. if it is true, then don't insert, if it has no data (false), insert a query.

Ex:

```
Select count(*) from twist_data where url='".$url."';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ON DUPLICATE` key words in your insert query. See: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY (do nothing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596390/insert-on-duplicate-key-do-nothing)

And set the column's index to unique.

Comment: The `on duplicate` is relevant **only** if you have a unique index.

Comment: Edited. Thanks. :)

Comment: Did you check my answer from 7 minutes ago? :) (a vote there will be appreciated)

Comment: I'm pretty sure yours will throw an error if you only set the index to unique. You have to also define what to do in that situation from my experience.

Comment: The `query(...)` will return false, but thats ok.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last two ligne with this code:
    `$query = "select * from twist_data where url='$url'";
    $db->query($query);
    if($db->num_rows>0){
    $query = "INSERT INTO twist_data ( url,theme ) VALUES ('$url','$theme')";
    $db->query($query);
    }`