# Insert into if not exists not inserting

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO my_table (field_1, field_2)
SELECT val_1, val_2     
FROM my_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT field_1
                        FROM my_table
                        WHERE field_2 = val_2)
LIMIT 1
```

I can not use unique index on field_2 field.
I'm trying to insert if not exists a tuple with field2 = val_2.
Without the "where" clause, this insert.
With the "where" clause **EVEN WHEN EMPTY TABLE**, it won't insert.

Any help on that?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This seems strange.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Of course it won't insert when the table is empty, you'd be selecting from an empty table. Try selecting from `DUAL` instead. _I'm assuming `val_1` and `val_2` are placeholders for literal values, otherwise the query wouldn't make any sense._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `val_1` and `val_2` are not columns of the table, right?
They are values that you want to insert in the table. 
So drop:

```
FROM my_table
```

and use:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (field_1, field_2)
SELECT val_1, val_2     
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT field_1
  FROM my_table
  WHERE field2 = val_2
)
```

Comment: Thanks.
You are a genius
May you explain why it does not work in the other case?

Comment: Your version with `FROM my_table`, returns as many rows as there are in my_table  when not exists is true. So if there are 100 rows the insert statement would attempt to insert 100 identical rows. I guess in your table maybe this is not allowed, right?

Comment: When the table is empty, your statement returns 0 rows so nothing is inserted.

Comment: curious thing is this:

SELECT val_1, val_2     
FROM my_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT field_1
                        FROM my_table
                        WHERE field_2 = val_2)
LIMIT 1

This part returns correctly val_1, val_2.
that is why I do not understand that.

Comment: I did not notice limit 1 at the end. Now if the table is empty your statement would **not** work for sure because FROM my_table returns nothing. If it is not empty, it should work when not exists returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is that check if key exist:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (field_1, field_2) ON DUPLICATE KEY INSERT IGNORE.
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596390/insert-on-duplicate-key-do-nothing) maybe useful.

Answer (score 0):

First create a unique index on the column or columns that you don't want duplicated.  I cannot tell if it is on both or just `field_2`:

```
create unique index unq_my_table_field_2 on my_table(field_2);
```

Then ignore the error using `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (field_1, field_2)
    VALUES (val_1, val_2)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field_2 = VALUES(val_2);   -- this is a no-op, because the value is already the same
```

The fact the your code doesn't work on an empty table has nothing to do with the `WHERE` clause but with using `from my_table` in the from clause.  If there are no rows, then the query returns . . . no rows.  No surprise there that nothing gets inserted.