# Use WHERE NOT EXISTS in same table with composite PK in Informix

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, informix

I have one table with a composite of 5 fields in an Informix database and I need to duplicate some values and just change the `rm_id` field. That part is already working. The problem comes when trying to duplicate it and one row with these 5 values already exists and I received a `Unique constraint violated` error. I started to write a query for this and I did this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.rm_id = 249
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.prop, t2.rb_code, t2.bm_id, t2.bl, t2.rm_id
FROM table t2
WHERE t2.prop = t1.prop, t2.rb_code = t1.rb_code, t2.bm_id = t1.bm_id, t2.bl = t1.bl, t2.rm_id = t1.rm_id);
```

I received a syntax error but I can't find any problem with my query; is there any way to do something like this in Informix?

Comment: see possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596390/insert-on-duplicate-key-do-nothing/4596409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AND instead of commas to separate the conditions in the WHERE clause.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table t1
 WHERE t1.rm_id = 249
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.prop, t2.rb_code, t2.bm_id, t2.bl, t2.rm_id
                     FROM table t2
                    WHERE t2.prop = t1.prop
                      AND t2.rb_code = t1.rb_code
                      AND t2.bm_id = t1.bm_id
                      AND t2.bl = t1.bl
                      AND t2.rm_id = t1.rm_i
                  );
```

Also, for a [NOT] EXISTS operation, it doesn't really matter what you list as the select-list items.  It is conventional to list `NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM …)`.